# Form still submits, trying to use e.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preventdefault, onsubmit

So I have this form. I want to check if user has validaty the captcha, but have problems. Here is the form, that checks the function.

```
<form data-id="embedded_signup:form" id="myForm" class="ctct-custom-form Form" name="embedded_signup" method="POST" action="https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup" onsubmit="check_if_capcha_is_filled()">
```

Here is the function that determines whether doSubmit (the captcha) has been validated.

```
function check_if_capcha_is_filled(e){
  if(doSubmit) return true;
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Fill in the capcha!');
  return false;
};
```

But I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
at check_if_capcha_is_filled
```

Any pointers to what I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: `onsubmit="return check_if_capcha_is_filled(event)"` Better yet, use `addEventListener` and remove the outdated `on*` event attribute

Comment: place `e.preventDefault();` at the first line inside the function

Comment: remove all inline js and css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintian code and unexpected behaviour  also, you're using preventDefault incorrectly, will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your e.preventDefault is being used incorrectly. It will do nothing because you're passing an event to a function, you want to attach it to the event handler like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of code
})
```

this will stop the submit action.

refs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
<form data-id="embedded_signup:form" id="myForm" class="ctct-custom-form Form" name="embedded_signup" method="POST" action="https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup">
```

Then in your js file:

```
function check_if_capcha_is_filled(){
    if (doSubmit){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};

$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
    if (!check_if_capcha_is_filled){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here. Firstly you need to `return` the function from the `onsubmit` event attriubute. Secondly, you're not passing the event in to the function - however this will only work where a global event is available, ie. not Firefox.

To fix the issue, and improve your logic, you can instead use `addEventListener()` to unobtrusively add the event handler to the element, and remove the outdated `on*` event attribute. Try this:

```js
var doSubmit = false;

document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (doSubmit) 
    return;
    
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Fill in the capcha!');
});
```

```html
<form data-id="embedded_signup:form" id="myForm" class="ctct-custom-form Form" name="embedded_signup" method="POST" action="https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event listener

change it to

```
<form data-id="embedded_signup:form" id="myForm" class="ctct-custom-form Form" name="embedded_signup" method="POST" action="https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup" >

 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    // validation code here
    if(!valid) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and if you want to confirm the submit.

```
<button name="delete" class="submitbutton">Delete</button>

$('.submitbutton').click(function() {
    var buttonpressed;
    buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name');
    var r = confirm("Please confirm to " + buttonpressed );

    if (r == true) {
        $('#yourformid').submit();
    } else {
        return (false);
    }
});
```